# Access Spock data provider variable from inside where: block

Tags: spring, groovy, spock

I'm trying to access a where block variable from within the where block and it is not working.  I'm thinking Spock doesn't allow this, but thought I'd give it a shot and see if anyone knows how to do it.

```java
where:
testNumber << Stream.iterate(1, n -> n).iterator()
test << Stream.generate(() -> { testNumber > 15 }).iterator()
```

Result:

```
No such property: testNumber for class
```

If this isn't possible and someone has an alternative way to accomplish something similar I'm open to that.  Basically I'm trying to make this test easier to manage, because keeping track of multiple arrays of 15-20 booleans is a bit of a pain:

```java
testNumber << [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
post << [false, false, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]
postWeekend << [true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
dividendReinvested << [true, false, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]
createCCB << [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true]
ntd << [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

But many of them I can set up based on the test number instead, if I can access it (and having the test number available also makes it easy to determine which test failed).

Comment: I think it would help, if you could add what you are trying to optmize. To me this looks like you try to permutate your tests over an infinite stream and another infinite stream?

Comment: This question is an example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898). Please explain **what** you are trying to achieve instead of just showing **how** you think it should be done technically. I am sure we can find a solution for your problem, but I do not even understand what your code is trying to do. Just show a simple, tedious way to do what you want (a big data table in the `where` block or whatever you used before the optimisation), so we know where we start optimising.

Comment: @kriegaex updated, let me know if unclear

Comment: @kriegaex I accepted Leonard's answer; I think that is what I need.

Comment: Yes, I agree after seeing your update. I am going to write another answer with additional details, because my guess was the same as Leonard's, I simply wanted to avoid publishing a speculative answer, because I was not sufficiently sure that it was what you wanted. Your original example code looked like you might have had a reason to use streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to calculate something based on `testNumber`.
You can use [data variables](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_data_variable_assignment) for that.

Another problem is that you are using an infinite stream, which will not terminate before the jvm will run out of memory. So you need to either use `.limit(20)` or just use a groovy range to define it more succinctly.

```
import spock.lang.*

class ASpec extends Specification {
  def "hello world"() {
    expect: 
    testNumber > 15 == test
      
    where:
    testNumber << (1..20)
    test = testNumber > 15 
  }
}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?codez=eJxljEEKwjAURNfmFENXrYtgBTelKXgBN54gJr82mCYliVSQ3t2abgSX8-bNmHHyISFOXj24le7O94wpK2PE-TqRAr0SOR3xDaY3SibjHd4M0NSjGMhaj9kHq4uyyhzrZpVTgxwSxXR5jjcK6FCfIERGucOmzAMFatjuR21blDXnx0O1YYi_o3W6sIV9AGIbOYY).

If that isn't what you wanted then you should update your question as @kriegaex suggested to tell us what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

*Please do not accept this answer, Leonard's one solved the original problem. I am just presenting some more details.*

The Spock manual explains how to [access other data variables](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.1-M2/all_in_one.html#_accessing_other_data_variables) inside a `where` block.

Additionally, if in another situation you only need the [iteration index](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.1-M2/all_in_one.html#_unrolled_iteration_names) in the unrolled method name, but not inside the feature method itself, you can use `#iterationIndex`. The count starts at index 0. Here is an example showing you both:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q70661506

import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

class ReferringToDataTableVariablesTest extends Specification {
  @Shared
  final n = 8

  def "feature [#iterationIndex]: #testNumber, #testRange"() {
    println "$testNumber, $testRange, ${testClosure()}"

    expect:
    true

    where:
    testNumber << (1..n)
    testRange = testNumber + 3..2 * testNumber
    testClosure = { -> testNumber / 2 > 2 }
  }
}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?codez=H4sICAU63mEAA1JlZmVycmluZ1RvRGF0YVRhYmxlVmFyaWFibGVzVGVzdC5ncm9vdnkAbU9NT8JAEL3vr5gUDuDHChjRECQmevHiAYgXY8zQTsuG7W7d3QoJ6X93KE1TEw-bnffmvTczBcY7zAgSkj52Zf6Vow_kpA_csD_kUm338vt-NJ2O70ZTIVReWBfAFzbeSY0mk6stOkr-axQUq1TFGJQ1QsQavYclpeScMtnavmDANW40vaNTp9-vyQegQyCTePhjh6MAeGpGAaTKoAYDj_AgGCaUQpQShtIRfPQUX1C7Xk1Ch88Z9AIHv5X5htzVGSx5QYoGwzoXoOCNgjYQ9bvKfqvk-ngCz9p6njEYVpGojXTgLcOsroMr6czut-SoIds8mM9hMJbSDNtGnc1HdESXcCvlBC46XCtvprPhCNeLrusGJrDgV7G2EpX4BTXG2__XAQAA).

In my IDE, running the test looks like this:

[image: IDE screenshot with unrolled test names and test log output]

Comment: iteration index is a great tip.